# Using queue to synchronize Tk object

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I'm trying to create a chess game using tkinter. I don't have a huge experience in python programming, but I kind of find weird the philosophy of tkinter : if my assumptions are correct, it seems to me that using tkinter means setting it as the **base** of the project, and everything has to work around it. And what I mean by that is that using whatever code that is not 'wrapped' in the tkinter framework is a pain to deal with (you **have** to use the event system, you **have** to use the `after` method if you want to perform an action after starting the main loop, etc.)

I have a rather different view on that, and in my chess project I simply consider the tkinter display as a part of **my** rendering system, and the event system provided by tkinter as a part of **my** input parser system. That being said, I want to be able to easily change the renderer or the input parser, which means that I could want to detect input from the terminal (for instance by writing `D2 D3`) instead of moving the objects on the screen. I could also want to print the chessboard on the terminal instead of having a GUI.

More to the point, because tkinter blocks the thread through the `mainloop` method instead of looping in another thread, I have to put my `Tk` object in a different thread, so that I can run the rest of my program in parallel. And I'm having a tough time doing it, because my `Tk` variable contained by my thread needs to be accessed by my program, to update it for instance.

After quite a bit of research, I found that queues in python were synchronized, which means that if I put my `Tk` object in a queue, I could access it without any problem from the main thread. I tried to see if the following code was working :

```py
import threading, queue

class VariableContainer(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue.Queue()

    def run(self):
        self.queue.put("test")

container = VariableContainer()
container.start()

print(container.queue.get(False))
```

and it does ! The output is `test`.
However, if I replace my test string by a `Tk` object, like below :

```py
import threading, queue
import tkinter

class VariableContainer(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue.Queue()

    def run(self):
        root = tkinter.Tk()
        self.queue.put(root)
        root.mainloop() # whether I call the mainloop or not doesn't change anything

container = VariableContainer()
container.start()

print(container.queue.get(False))
```

then the print throws an error, stating that the queue is empty.

(Note that the code above is not the code of my program, it is just an exemple since posting sample codes from my project might be less clear)

Why?

Comment: I just let tkinter be and use mainloop(). I then put all my other code in one or more other threads, only communicating back to the GUI via a synchronised queue.

Comment: that's what I would like to avoid. I don't want tkinter to rule the main thread, it's just an optional feature that I could replace by any other GUI framework, or even by a terminal

Comment: @Akami: Running Tkinter in the main thread is sort of hard to avoid. Same with basically any other GUI framework. I would rather split the program into the server / engine part, which talks some simple protocol, and a GUI part that talks to it according to external events like user actions or timers. Python's `multiprocessing` module even helps with setting up a communication channel abstracted from the platform (queues).

Comment: why do they do that? I'm much more experienced with java programming, and I've never seen any framework do that. I'll definitely check that multiprocessing module, thanks for the comment!

Comment: @Akami: Because no real threads exist in Python (and Ruby, JavaScript, similarly). Else every object access would have to be synchronized. So only semi-cooperative multithreading can be implemented, [using a global lock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock). Such threads are good for I/O waiting, and are better than cooperative concurrency with explicit yield points, but totally don't work with anything CPU-bound.

Comment: seems like complicated, I have so little experience in multithreading...

Comment: @Akami: The only difference with Java is that the “main thread” (*i.e.*, the one that calls `main`) isn’t the same as the event-dispatch thread.  It’s still the case that you have to synchronize if you want to do any processing that doesn’t block the dispatch of (further) events.  Compared to that, actually starting your own thread is trivial.

Comment: well as I mentioned earlier I know very little about threading, but my point was that I've never seen a framework that requires you to put all your logic in a different thread because the main one is occupied by the framework

Comment: @Akami: You have—at least, in the equivalent sense I described—whether you’ve recognized it or not.  In simple cases, program logic that isn’t time-consuming is put *in* the event handlers, so it doesn’t come up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the trivial question you actually asked: you have a **race condition** because you call `Queue.get(block=False)`.  Tk taking a lot longer to initialize, the main thread almost always wins and finds the queue still empty.

The real question is “How do I **isolate** my logic from the structure of my interface library?”.  (While I understand the desire for a simple **branch** point between “read from the keyboard” and “wait for a mouse event”, it is considered more composable, in the face of large numbers of event types, sources, and handlers, to have one event dispatcher provided by the implementation.  It can sometimes be driven one event at a time, but that composes less well with other logic than one might think.)

The usual answer to that is to make your logic a **state machine** rather than an algorithm.  Mechanically, this means replacing local variables with **attributes** on an object and dividing the code into **methods** on its class (*e.g.*, one call per “read from keyboard” in a monolithic implementation).  Sometimes language features like **coroutines** can be used to make this transformation mostly transparent/automatic, but they’re not always a good fit.  For example:

```
def algorithm(n):
  tot=0
  for i in range(n):
    s=int(input("#%s:"%i))
    tot+=(i+1)*(n-i)*s
  print(tot)

class FSM(object):
  def __init__(self,n):
    self.n=n
    self.i=self.tot=0
  def send(self,s):
    self.tot+=(self.i+1)*(self.n-self.i)*s
    self.i+=1
  def count(self): return self.i
  def done(self): return self.i>=self.n
  def get(self):
    return self.tot

def coroutine(n):  # old-style, not "async def"
  tot=0
  for i in range(n):
    s=(yield)
    tot+=(i+1)*(n-i)*s
  yield tot
```

Having done this, it’s trivial to **layer** the traditional stream-driven I/O back on top, or to connect it to an event-driven system (be it a GUI or `asyncio`).  For example:

```
def fsmClient(n):
  fsm=FSM(n)
  while not fsm.done():
    fsm.send(int(input("#%s:"%fsm.count())))
  return fsm.get()

def coClient(n):
  co=coroutine(n)
  first=True
  while True:
    ret=co.send(None if first else
                int(input("#%s:"%fsm.count())))
    if ret is not None:
      co.close()
      return ret
    first=False
```

These clients can work with any state machine/coroutine using the same **interface**; it should be obvious how to instead supply values from a Tkinter input box or so.

Comment: I can't understand what you mean by a state machine. Could you provide an example ? I don't mind using the event system of tkinter, but what about events that are not handled by the framework, such as basic console inputs ?

Comment: @Akami: You can in fact run `select` through Tkinter to handle any kind of file descriptors.

Comment: Thank you for the example. Using get() instead of get(False) indeed solved the problem